# Filter Array of Objects by fields of Object that have arrays inside

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of articles. For example:

```
var articles = [
    {
        id: '1',
        createdAt: new Date(2017, 3, 5, 8, 0),
        title: '«Title 1',
        summary: 'Summary 1',
        author: 'John',
        content: 'Content 1',
        tags: ['tag1'],
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        createdAt: new Date(2017, 4, 5, 8, 0),
        title: '«Title 2',
        summary: 'Summary 2',
        author: 'Bob',
        content: 'Content 2',
        tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        createdAt: new Date(2017, 5, 5, 8, 0),
        title: '«Title 3',
        summary: 'Summary 3',
        author: 'Jeremy',
        content: 'Content 3',
        tags: ['tag2'],
}];
```

And i have filterConfig

```
var filterConfig =
{
    createdAtFrom: new Date(2017, 3, 5, 8, 0),
    createdAtTo:new Date(2017, 5, 5, 8, 0),
    author: 'Bob',
    tags: ['tag1,tag2'],
};
```

So i need to filter my articles by this filter config. It can consist all fields or some of them. And my function getArticles should return filtered array of articles. Filtered array should also consist all tags mentioned in filterConfig, but if article consist 3 tags and 2 of them are in the filterConfig, function should return it. And also articles from range in filterConfig.
In my example if should return

```
{
    id: '2',
    createdAt: new Date(2017, 4, 5, 8, 0),
    title: '«Title 2',
    summary: 'Summary 2',
    author: 'Bob',
    content: 'Content 2',
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
}
```

What if the best way to do this? Should I write if for all filds or it is something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have four types of tests: a from-test, a to-test, an array-test, and a equality test.

I would iterate over the array, then over each config property, and finally detect which of the four tests has to be performed, and perform it.

Here is some ES6 code doing that:

```
articles.filter( article => {
    return Object.keys(filterConfig).every( key => {
        const [prop, operator] = key.match(/^(.*?)(From|To)?$/).slice(1),
            value = article[prop],
            testValue = filterConfig[key];
        return operator === 'From' ? value >= testValue
             : operator === 'To' ? value <= testValue
             : Array.isArray(value) ? testValue.every( test => value.includes(test) )
             : value === testValue;
    });
});
```

```js
var articles = [
{
    id: '1',
    createdAt: new Date(2017, 3, 5, 8, 0),
    title: '«Title 1',
    summary: 'Summary 1',
    author: 'John',
    content: 'Content 1',
    tags: ['tag1'],
},
{
    id: '2',
    createdAt: new Date(2017, 4, 5, 8, 0),
    title: '«Title 2',
    summary: 'Summary 2',
    author: 'Bob',
    content: 'Content 2',
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
},
{
    id: '3',
    createdAt: new Date(2017, 5, 5, 8, 0),
    title: '«Title 3',
    summary: 'Summary 3',
    author: 'Jeremy',
    content: 'Content 3',
    tags: ['tag2'],
}];

var filterConfig = {
    createdAtFrom: new Date(2017, 3, 5, 8, 0),
    createdAtTo:new Date(2017, 5, 5, 8, 0),
    author: 'Bob',
    tags: ['tag1','tag2'],
};

const result = articles.filter( article => {
    return Object.keys(filterConfig).every( key => {
        const [prop, operator] = key.match(/^(.*?)(From|To)?$/).slice(1),
            value = article[prop],
            testValue = filterConfig[key];
        return operator === 'From' ? value >= testValue
             : operator === 'To' ? value <= testValue
             : Array.isArray(value) ? testValue.every( test => value.includes(test) )
             : value === testValue;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: the `tags` property had an issue in your question: the array had only one value. I assumed it had to be `['tag1','tag2']` instead of `['tag1,tag2']`.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. In my answer, I went with returning false on the first fail to avoid doing an unnecessary processing afterwards. I also used  a for loop instead of using every in order to return false on the first fail in the loop.

Comment: @CodeToad, this code also returns `false` on the first fail. That is how `every` works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to write an if block for every property in the filter config, since they are optional.

One approach is to run a test for every property in the filterConfig. if it fails, return false in the filter, at the end, return true. so every article will be included in the result by default unless it failed one of the filter checks.

[Here is something to get you started](https://jsfiddle.net/7bvkqqz5/1/):

```
  var articles = [
    {
        id: '1',
        createdAt: new Date(2017, 3, 5, 8, 0),
        title: '«Title 1',
        summary: 'Summary 1',
        author: 'John',
        content: 'Content 1',
        tags: ['tag1'],
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        createdAt: new Date(2017, 4, 5, 8, 0),
        title: '«Title 2',
        summary: 'Summary 2',
        author: 'Bob',
        content: 'Content 2',
        tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        createdAt: new Date(2017, 5, 5, 8, 0),
        title: '«Title 3',
        summary: 'Summary 3',
        author: 'Jeremy',
        content: 'Content 3',
        tags: ['tag2'],
}];

var filterConfig =
{
    createdAtFrom: new Date(2017, 3, 5, 8, 0),
    createdAtTo:new Date(2017, 5, 5, 8, 0),
    author: 'Bob',
    tags: ['tag1,tag2'],
};


function filterArticles(articles, config){

return articles.filter(function(a){


if(config.createdAtFrom && config.createdAtFrom < a.createdAt){
return false;
}
if(config.createdAtTo && config.createdAtTo > a.createdAt){
return false;
}

if(config.author && config.author  !== a.author){
return false;
}

if(config.tags){
 for (var i = 0; i < config.tags.length; i++) {
        if(atricle.tags.indexOf(config.tags[i]) === -1 ){
        return false;
        }   
    }
}


return true;

});

}

console.log(filterArticles(articles, filterConfig))

console.log(filterArticles(articles, {  author: 'John'}))
```